# Export a DynamoDB table as CSV through AWS CLI (without using pipeline)

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am new to AWS CLI and I am trying to export my DynamoDB table in CSV format so that I can import it directly into PostgreSQL. Is there a way to do that using AWS CLI?

I came across this command: `aws dynamodb scan --table-name <table-name>` - but this does not provide an option of a CSV export.

With this command, I can see the output in my terminal but I am not sure how to write it into a file.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If all items have the same attributes, e.g. `id` and `name` both of which are strings, then run:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
    --table-name mytable \
    --query "Items[*].[id.S,name.S]" \
    --output text
```

That would give tab-separated output. You can redirect this to file using `> output.txt`, and you could then easily convert tabs into commas for csv.

Note that you may need to paginate per the [scan documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html):

> If the total number of scanned items exceeds the maximum dataset size limit of 1 MB, the scan stops and results are returned to the user as a LastEvaluatedKey value to continue the scan in a subsequent operation. The results also include the number of items exceeding the limit. A scan can result in no table data meeting the filter criteria.

Another option is the [DynamoDBtoCSV](https://github.com/edasque/DynamoDBtoCSV) project at github.

Comment: All items have same attributes, but data types are different. Will this query work with different data types ?

Comment: Just supply the appropriate data types in that case, for example: name.S, zipcode.N, isawesome.B.

Comment: is there a different way to achieve that? because my output is showed up in console and this takes alot of time for large data...

Comment: @Khan a web search will yield other options for exporting DynamoDB tables, but the key factor impacting performance will be the provisioned read capacity of the table (RCU). You may want to increase that temporarily, do the export, then dial it back down.

Comment: @jarmod how can I limit the number of entries? Can you share any documentation that might come handy to me?

Comment: @n0obcoder the scan actually limits the number of returned results implicitly (I'll update the answer) but you can also supply `--max-items N`. See the [aws dynamodb scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html) docs.

Comment: Do not work when some cols are missing in some items

Comment: @StéphaneM correct and the answer does state that upfront.

Answer (score 27):

A better way to do a full export of all columns without listign out is at [Dynamo db export to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054868/dynamo-db-export-to-csv/61805559#61805559)

basically

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name my-table --select ALL_ATTRIBUTES --page-size 500 --max-items 100000 --output json | jq -r '.Items' | jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, map([.[ $keys[] ].S])[] | @csv' > export.my-table.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution! Downside is that if the field is a Set it seems to be empty...in which case you would need to use the answer from above

Comment: The .S means this only works for string fields. Replacing that with .N works for number fields only. How can you make it work for strings and numbers at the same time?

Comment: It works out of the box for me, only had to change the table name. It should be the top answer.

Comment: One of my fields could contain Persian characters, and the whole column called 'error' was skipped because of it.

Comment: I improved jq command, should support all types: jq -r '.Items' | jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, map([.[ $keys[] ] | to_entries[] | [.value][0]])[] | @csv'

Answer (score 19):

For localhost dynamodb:

```
$aws dynamodb scan --table-name AOP --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url
http://localhost:8000 --output json > /home/ohelig/Desktop/a.json
```

For dynamodb:

```
$aws dynamodb scan --table-name AOP --region us-east-1 --output json > /home/ohelig/Desktop/a.json
```

Then Convert JSON to CSV or whatever.

I have modified above answer to make it clear.

Comment: The question was to get a CSV from a DynamoDB table. There are many ways to dump DynamoDB tables, including local DynamoDB, but it's non-trivial to convert DynamoDB JSON to CSV.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) convert the json output given by aws cli to csv

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name mytable --query "Items[*].[id.S,name.S]" --output json | jq -r '.[] | @csv' > dump.csv
```

Comment: I get `jq: error (at <stdin>:1811): array ([{"N":"1559...) is not valid in a csv row`

Comment: I like this answer the best.

Comment: this won't work if you have a map type though

Comment: you mean map type of attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) to convert json into csv

```sh
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name <table-name> \
    --index-name <index-name> \
    --select SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES \
    --projection-expression "attributes1, attributes2,..." \
    --key-condition-expression "#index1 = :index1 AND #index2 = :index2" \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#index1": "index1","#index2": "index2"}' \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":index1": {"S":"key1"},":index2": {"S":"key2"}}' \
    --output json | jq -r '.Items' | jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, map([.[ $keys[] ][]?])[] | @csv' > output.csv
```

But be careful if the column data length is different it will produce wrong output