# Dynamo db export to csv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a serverless project, I'm trying to export Dynamo DB tables into single csv, and then upload it to S3.

All npm modules i checked export single table. Is there a way to export multiple table data into one single csv?

Answer (score 6):

To export as a CSV, adding onto @dixon1e post, use `jq` in the shell. With DynamoDb run:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name my-table --select ALL_ATTRIBUTES --page-size 500 --max-items 100000 --output json | jq -r '.Items' | jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, map([.[ $keys[] ].S])[] | @csv' > export.my-table.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

The AWS CLI can be used to download data from Dynamo DB:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name my-table --select ALL_ATTRIBUTES --page-size 500 --max-items 100000
```

The --page-size is important, there is a limit of 1M (megabyte) for every query result.

Comment: It scans the table and returns a DynamoDB DSL style objects in JSON format.
To make this a CSV you'll need more work around this