# AWS CLI - Extracting the result of a dynamodb query to csv file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, jq, aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

I'm having an error when I run a command to extract data to a csv file, using the AWS CLI with jq.

Command:
`aws dynamodb scan --table-name MyTable --select ALL_ATTRIBUTES --page-size 500 --max-items 100000 --output json --profile production | jq -r '.Items' | jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, map([.[ $keys[] ].S])[] | @csv' > export.my-table.csv`

Error:
`'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-3: character maps to <undefined> parse error: Unfinished JSON term at EOF at line 5097, column 21`

Comment: Does this help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357821/export-a-dynamodb-table-as-csv-through-aws-cli-without-using-pipeline

Comment: It looks like the json file is not valid. Maybe the transmission is incomplete?
Have you had a look at line 5097?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is a query that I wrote previously that does not work on nested attributes. You will have to modify it accordingly.